# Nhibernate: Unrecognized Guid format - could not execute query

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

i'm trying to mapping an existing databases into Nhibernate but when i execute a query i receive the following error:

InnerException = {"Unrecognized Guid format."}

Message = "could not execute query [ SELECT * FROM carte WHERE custom_id = ?p0 ]\r\n  Name:custom_id Value:111 [SQL: SELECT * FROM carte WHERE custom_id = ?p0]"

I'm not able to locate the error could someone help me?

Info:
The project is a wpf on .net core 3.1.
Nhibernate 5.3.0
MySql.Data 8.0.21

Db: Mysql ( if i use "sandard" sql connection everything works)

Here is my map hbm file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping assembly="CenturionCommanderTools" namespace="CenturionCommanderTools.Database.Models" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Carte" table="carte" lazy="false" >
    <id name="custom_id" column="custom_id" type="UInt64">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="arena_id">
      <column name="arena_id" sql-type="int(11)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="id">
      <column name="id" sql-type="char(36)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="language">
      <column name="language" sql-type="varchar(255)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="mtgo_id">
      <column name="mtgo_id" sql-type="int(11)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="mtgo_foil_id">
      <column name="mtgo_foil_id" sql-type="int(11)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="multiverse_ids">
      <column name="multiverse_ids" sql-type="text" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="tcgplayer_id">
      <column name="tcgplayer_id" sql-type="int(11)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="card_object">
      <column name="object" sql-type="varchar(255)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="oracle_id">
      <column name="oracle_id" sql-type="char(36)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="prints_search_uri">
      <column name="prints_search_uri" sql-type="text" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="rulings_uri">
      <column name="rulings_uri" sql-type="text" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="scryfall_uri">
      <column name="scryfall_uri" sql-type="text" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="uri_cdb">
      <column name="uri" sql-type="text" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="all_parts">
      <column name="all_parts" sql-type="text" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="card_faces">
      <column name="card_faces" sql-type="text" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="cmc">
      <column name="cmc" sql-type="float" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="colors">
      <column name="colors" sql-type="text" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="color_identity">
      <column name="color_identity" sql-type="text" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="color_indicator">
      <column name="color_indicator" sql-type="text" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="edhrec_rank">
      <column name="edhrec_rank" sql-type="int(11)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="foil">
      <column name="foil" sql-type="tinyint(1)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="hand_modifier">
      <column name="hand_modifier" sql-type="varchar(255)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="layout">
      <column name="layout" sql-type="varchar(255)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="legalities">
      <column name="legalities" sql-type="text" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="life_modifier">
      <column name="life_modifier" sql-type="varchar(255)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="loyalty">
      <column name="loyalty" sql-type="varchar(255)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="mana_cost">
      <column name="mana_cost" sql-type="varchar(255)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="name_card">
      <column name="name" sql-type="varchar(255)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="nonfoil">
      <column name="nonfoil" sql-type="tinyint(1)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="oracle_text">
      <column name="oracle_text" sql-type="text" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="oversized">
      <column name="oversized" sql-type="tinyint(1)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="power">
      <column name="power" sql-type="varchar(255)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="reserved">
      <column name="reserved" sql-type="tinyint(1)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="toughness">
      <column name="toughness" sql-type="varchar(255)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="type_line">
      <column name="type_line" sql-type="varchar(255)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="artist">
      <column name="artist" sql-type="varchar(255)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="booster">
      <column name="booster" sql-type="tinyint(1)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="border_color">
      <column name="border_color" sql-type="varchar(255)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="card_back_id">
      <column name="card_back_id" sql-type="char(36)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="collector_number">
      <column name="collector_number" sql-type="varchar(255)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="digital">
      <column name="digital" sql-type="tinyint(1)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="flavor_text">
      <column name="flavor_text" sql-type="text" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="frame_effect">
      <column name="frame_effect" sql-type="varchar(255)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="frame">
      <column name="frame" sql-type="varchar(255)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="full_art">
      <column name="full_art" sql-type="tinyint(1)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="games">
      <column name="games" sql-type="text" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="highres_image">
      <column name="highres_image" sql-type="tinyint(1)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="illustration_id">
      <column name="illustration_id" sql-type="char(36)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="image_uris">
      <column name="image_uris" sql-type="text" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="prices">
      <column name="prices" sql-type="text" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="printed_name">
      <column name="printed_name" sql-type="varchar(255)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="printed_text">
      <column name="printed_text" sql-type="text" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="printed_type_line">
      <column name="printed_type_line" sql-type="varchar(255)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="promo">
      <column name="promo" sql-type="tinyint(1)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="promo_types">
      <column name="promo_types" sql-type="text" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="purchase_uris">
      <column name="purchase_uris" sql-type="text" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="rarity">
      <column name="rarity" sql-type="varchar(255)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="related_uris">
      <column name="related_uris" sql-type="text" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="released_at">
      <column name="released_at" sql-type="date" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="reprint">
      <column name="reprint" sql-type="tinyint(1)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="scryfall_set_uri">
      <column name="scryfall_set_uri" sql-type="text" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="set_name">
      <column name="set_name" sql-type="varchar(255)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="set_search_uri">
      <column name="set_search_uri" sql-type="text" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="set_type">
      <column name="set_type" sql-type="varchar(255)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="set_uri">
      <column name="set_uri" sql-type="text" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="set">
      <column name="set" sql-type="varchar(255)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="story_spotlight">
      <column name="story_spotlight" sql-type="tinyint(1)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="textless">
      <column name="textless" sql-type="tinyint(1)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="variation">
      <column name="variation" sql-type="tinyint(1)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="variation_of">
      <column name="variation_of" sql-type="char(36)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="watermark">
      <column name="watermark" sql-type="varchar(255)" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="created_at">
      <column name="created_at" sql-type="timestamp" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="updated_at">
      <column name="updated_at" sql-type="timestamp" not-null="false" />
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Map class:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace CenturionCommanderTools.Database.Models {

    [Serializable]
    public class Carte {
        public virtual UInt64 custom_id { get; set; }
        public virtual int? arena_id { get; set; }
        public virtual string id { get; set; }
        public virtual string language { get; set; }
        public virtual int? mtgo_id { get; set; }
        public virtual int? mtgo_foil_id { get; set; }
        public virtual string multiverse_ids { get; set; }
        public virtual int? tcgplayer_id { get; set; }
        public virtual string card_object { get; set; }
        public virtual string oracle_id { get; set; }
        public virtual string prints_search_uri { get; set; }
        public virtual string rulings_uri { get; set; }
        public virtual string scryfall_uri { get; set; }
        public virtual string uri_cdb { get; set; }
        public virtual string all_parts { get; set; }
        public virtual string card_faces { get; set; }
        public virtual float? cmc { get; set; }
        public virtual string colors { get; set; }
        public virtual string color_identity { get; set; }
        public virtual string color_indicator { get; set; }
        public virtual int? edhrec_rank { get; set; }
        public virtual int? foil { get; set; }
        public virtual string hand_modifier { get; set; }
        public virtual string layout { get; set; }
        public virtual string legalities { get; set; }
        public virtual string life_modifier { get; set; }
        public virtual string loyalty { get; set; }
        public virtual string mana_cost { get; set; }
        public virtual string name_card { get; set; }
        public virtual int? nonfoil { get; set; }
        public virtual string oracle_text { get; set; }
        public virtual int? oversized { get; set; }
        public virtual string power { get; set; }
        public virtual int? reserved { get; set; }
        public virtual string toughness { get; set; }
        public virtual string type_line { get; set; }
        public virtual string artist { get; set; }
        public virtual int? booster { get; set; }
        public virtual string border_color { get; set; }
        public virtual string card_back_id { get; set; }
        public virtual string collector_number { get; set; }
        public virtual int? digital { get; set; }
        public virtual string flavor_text { get; set; }
        public virtual string frame_effect { get; set; }
        public virtual string frame { get; set; }
        public virtual int? full_art { get; set; }
        public virtual string games { get; set; }
        public virtual int? highres_image { get; set; }
        public virtual string illustration_id { get; set; }
        public virtual string image_uris { get; set; }
        public virtual string prices { get; set; }
        public virtual string printed_name { get; set; }
        public virtual string printed_text { get; set; }
        public virtual string printed_type_line { get; set; }
        public virtual int? promo { get; set; }
        public virtual string promo_types { get; set; }
        public virtual string purchase_uris { get; set; }
        public virtual string rarity { get; set; }
        public virtual string related_uris { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? released_at { get; set; }
        public virtual int? reprint { get; set; }
        public virtual string scryfall_set_uri { get; set; }
        public virtual string set_name { get; set; }
        public virtual string set_search_uri { get; set; }
        public virtual string set_type { get; set; }
        public virtual string set_uri { get; set; }
        public virtual string set { get; set; }
        public virtual int? story_spotlight { get; set; }
        public virtual int? textless { get; set; }
        public virtual int? variation { get; set; }
        public virtual string variation_of { get; set; }
        public virtual string watermark { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? created_at { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? updated_at { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The code that explode:

```
        #region Get
        public List<Carte> getCardById(UInt64 cardId)
        {
          // cardId is 111
         // Called by:
         // UInt64 h = 111;
         // var card = cardsProvider.getCardById(h);
            try
            {
                sessione = factory.OpenSession();

                //Build the Query to fetch ONLY the contacts for that user
                var sqlQuery = sessione.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM carte WHERE custom_id = :custom_id");
                //Substitute parameter userid after the : with the input userid
                sqlQuery.SetParameter("custom_id", cardId);
                //Fect all the records, transform them into the mapped class contacts, turned them into a list of Contacts (derived from the ISession class) and...well, cast it to list
                return sqlQuery.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<Carte>()).List<Carte>().ToList();
                
                //This also explode
                //var card =  sessione.Get<Carte>(cardId);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {               
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (sessione.IsOpen)
                    sessione.Close();
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

Nhibernate config:

```
            try
            {
                var cfg = new Configuration();
                cfg.DataBaseIntegration(x => {
                    x.ConnectionString = Config.Config.getConfig().Connection.First().connectionStrig;
                    x.Driver<MySqlDataDriver>();
                    x.Dialect<MySQLDialect>();
                });
                cfg.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
                this.factory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
```

Slice of db:

[Db screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fwdj.png)

Comment: Can you also mention the data type for column in this     sqlQuery.SetParameter

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to make 'sessione.Get(cardId)' and get the same error ? (i think you will get the same error)

According to the [documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nhibernate/nhibernate_data_types_mapping.htm) there is no type "UInt64" for nhibernate, but simply "Int64". I think the problem is related to this.

I hope i helped you !

Comment: You're right! 

After changing from Uint64 to Int64 and change my connection string adding "old guids=true" ( the db is a little bit old... ) both query work perfectly!